# Convert from aspx page content to MS Word Format

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
Response.ContentType = "application/word";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=TestPage.doc");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Response.Write(sw);
Response.End();
Response.Flush();
```

I am trying to convert from aspx page to word format. When i launch the MS Word file generated it displays the dialog box
Problems during load
Missing file: c:\Content\Site.css

Looks like it is unable to load the css file. What is the solution. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following headers:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word"); Response.AddHeader("Expires: 0");Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

Regards